# underflow in restore in android 4.3

Tags: android

I'm getting a **IllegalStateException: underflow in restore exception,** which is causing my application to crash.
This started happening after android 4.3 update. On android 3.0 - 4.2.x it works fine.

The exception happens on the second

```
canvas.restore();
```

Given below is my drawing code

```
private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(mTickerBackGround!=null && (!mTickerBackGround.isRecycled())){
            canvas.drawBitmap(mTickerBackGround, 0, 0, null);
        }
        if((mBitMapBuffer!=null)){
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(mX, 0);
            if(!mBitMapBuffer.isRecycled()){
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitMapBuffer, 0, 0, null);
            }
            canvas.restore();

            if(bitMapWidth+mX<mCanvasWidth){
                canvas.translate(bitMapWidth+mX, 0);    
                if(!mBitMapBuffer.isRecycled()){
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitMapBuffer, 0, 0, null);
                }
                canvas.restore();                   
            }

            if(bitMapWidth+mX<=0){
                mX = 0;
            }else if(Math.abs(mX)>(bitMapWidth)){                   
                mX= mCanvasWidth; 
            }

            mX-=TickerConstants.SCROLLING_SMOOTHNESS*density;;
        }
        if(mLogo!=null && (!mLogo.isRecycled())){
            canvas.drawBitmap(mLogo, mCanvasWidth-(60*density), mLogo.getHeight()/6, null);
        }
    }
```

My question is

1. What is the meaning of this error?
2. How do i fix this error?

Stack trace message generated is . Line 165 corresponds to second canvas.restore()

> 08-13 18:13:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(14139): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   Thread-506 08-13 18:13:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(14139):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore 08-13
>   18:13:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(14139):    at
>   android.graphics.Canvas.restore(Native Method) 08-13 18:13:09.083:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14139):  at
>   com.my.package.name.ticker.TickerSurfaceView$TickerThread.doDraw(TickerSurfaceView.java:165)
>   08-13 18:13:09.083: E/AndroidRuntime(14139):  at
>   com.my.package.name.ticker.TickerSurfaceView$TickerThread.run(TickerSurfaceView.java:128)

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The bug is in this section of your code:

```
    if(bitMapWidth+mX<mCanvasWidth){
        canvas.translate(bitMapWidth+mX, 0);    
        if(!mBitMapBuffer.isRecycled()){
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitMapBuffer, 0, 0, null);
        }
        canvas.restore();                   
    }
```

You are calling `restore()` without calling `save()` first. You don't even need that call to `translate()` either, you could just pass the x and y coordinates to the `drawBitmap()` call.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try that. Could you please also explain, what the exception message mean ?

Comment: So i tried your suggestion and it is not crashing now. I've also incorporated your suggestion regarding the translate call. I'll continue testing on some OS variations. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I encountered very similar issue except in my case the offending code is closed-source from a 3rd party vendor. We're currently chasing the vendor to fix, but in the meantime is there any other alternative -- eg: restoring behavior of sdk 4.2.2 < ?

Comment: It also worked for me, i just put a canvas.save() before and it worked

Answer (score 3):

public void restore ()

Added in API level 1
This call balances a previous call to save(), and is used to remove all modifications to the matrix/clip state since the last save call. It is an error to call restore() more times than save() was called.